# php select из mssql не корректно работает

Tags: php, sql-server, веб-программирование

```
$sql = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname='$Fname'";
$result = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$sql);                                            
echo $result;
```

Почему без:

```
WHERE Pname='$Fname'
```

возвращает значение `Resursid#6`, а если добавляю переменную ничего не возвращает?

Comment: $result это не полученные данные, а дескриптор результата запроса, далее необходимо выполнять fetch функции, чтобы извлечь данные по дескриптору.

Comment: примеры в доках http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: неа не работает :С

Answer (score 1):

1. Вместо `echo $result;` используйте `var_dump($result);` и вы увидите, что вам вернулось в ответ в действительности (например `false`);
2. Прежде чем задавать вопросы изучите документацию по [Драйверу СУБД Microsoft SQL Server для PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlsrv.php) и посмотрите примеры использования функций:

   ```
   <?php
   $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
   if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }

   $sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
   $params = array(1, "some data");

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
   if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
   ```

Comment: инсерт не показательный) селект более наглядный пример  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я смотрю на вопросы автора и думаю, что без разницы какие примеры писать в ответах :)

Comment: это да)) а как же дух сообщэства?))))

Comment: прочитал ман, сделал, заработало но!
$sql = "SELECT Ptittle FROM dbo.Pcontent WHERE Pname=$Fname";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt);
  echo $row['Ptittle'];

Comment: хоть я и говорю ему что мне нужен именно этот эллемент массива, он мне выводит все полностью:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4104 [code] => 4104 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]"mopr.php". [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]"mopr.php". ) )
а значения которое лежит в ячейке нет

Comment: У вас до сих пор ошибка: `SQLSTATE 42000 («синтаксическая ошибка или нарушение прав доступа»)`